# Conditional Formatting based on Another Cell Date

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I would like a column to change color when in a cell there's a matching date from a determined range (Named Range).

```
                                    Column to
Dates_range          Match cell     change color
    A        . . .       D               E     
01/12/2020         --------------      Laura
15/12/2020         | 08/01/2021 |      Conan
08/01/2021         --------------      Dirk
                                      Martha
```

[image]

I have tried the custom formulas:

```
=D1=(OR(Date1;Date2;....DateX)
=OR(D1=Date1;D1=Date2;D1=Date3;...)
=D1=(INDIRECT("Dates_Range")
=D1=(Dates_Range)
```

But none have worked. Little help?

Comment: So is it just Conan that you want in red or the whole column? Could you share an image as well or the test sheet?

Comment: Added an image with the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following as your conditional rule

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B$2,A$2:A$5,0),FALSE)
```

[image]

If empty cells are also included in your range, try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A5<>"",IFERROR(MATCH(B$2,A$2:A$5,0),FALSE),FALSE))
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Out of curiosity. Which one did you finally use? 1st or 2nd?

Comment: 1st this time. Going to match against a static list of holidays.